# Proving the converse of Menelaus’s Theorem

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I want to prove the following:

If $\frac{BX}{CX}$$\frac{CY}{AY}$$\frac{AZ}{BZ}=1$, then X, Y and Z are collinear. I have attached what I have got so far, however I am struggling to understand the details for the final part.

[image]

My issue comes with the next part, which is how to prove the result when the ratios don’t equal one.

The hint is “Prove that there is only one point $X’$ such that $\frac{BX’}{CX’}=c$ where $c$ is any real number besides $1$”

However, I am not completely sure how to prove this result or how it would lead to the desired outcome. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$BX:CX=BX':CX'$$
$$(BX-CX):CX=(BX'-CX'):CX'$$
But $BX-CX=BX'-CX'=BC$ (provided both $X,X'$ are on the right with respect to $C$...), therefore:
$$BC:CX=BC:CX' \Rightarrow CX=CX' \Rightarrow X\equiv X'$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec{ZY}=-\vec{AZ}+\vec{AY}=-\frac{AZ}{AB}\vec{AB}+\frac{AY}{AC}\vec{AC}=-\frac{AZ}{AZ+BZ}\vec{AB}+\frac{AY}{AY+CY}\vec{AC}.$$
Also, $$\vec{ZX}=\vec{ZB}+\vec{BX}=\frac{BZ}{AZ+BZ}\vec{AB}+\frac{BX}{BX-CX}\vec{BC}=$$
$$=\frac{BZ}{AZ+BZ}\vec{AB}+\frac{BX}{BX-CX}\left(-\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}\right)=$$
$$=\left(\frac{BZ}{AZ+BZ}-\frac{BX}{BX-CX}\right)\vec{AB}+\frac{BX}{BX-CX}\vec{AC}=$$
$$=-\frac{BX\cdot AZ+BZ\cdot CX}{(AZ+BZ)(BX-CX)}\vec{AB}+\frac{BX}{BX-CX}\vec{AC}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that $$\vec{ZY}||\vec{ZX}$$ or
$$\frac{-\frac{BX\cdot AZ+BZ\cdot CX}{(AZ+BZ)(BX-CX)}}{-\frac{AZ}{AZ+BZ}}=\frac{\frac{BX}{BX-CX}}{\frac{AY}{AY+CY}}$$ or
$$\frac{BX\cdot AZ+BZ\cdot CX}{AZ}=\frac{BX(AY+CY)}{AY}$$ or
$$AY\cdot BZ\cdot CX=AZ\cdot BX\cdot CY$$ and we are done!